# Deploy play app using artifact

Tags: maven, sbt, playframework-2.1

I've published my playframework app to a maven repository using the steps mentioned in http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ProductionDist

How do I use that artifact to start my app?

Thanks!